# JavaScript function scope - why am I allowed to attach event handlers to unnamed elements?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The usual approach I would take to manipulating the DOM (in JavaScript) is to create or select an element, and then attach event handlers to the element.

That makes sense to me: the element has a form of identification, and that identification is used to determine which script/event handler/function is attached to it.

However, that can't be the full story, since I wrote the following code, and I was a little surprised to see that it worked:

```js
makeElement("test1")
makeElement("test2")
makeElement("test3") 
      
function makeElement (aName){
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  el.textContent = aName;

  el.onclick = function () {
    el.textContent = "ummmm"
  }
  document.body.appendChild(el)
}
```

The function creates an element, and attaches an .onclick event to the element that was made. However, I forgot to give the element a name or id, so what identifier is being used to map the event to the correct div?

In summary, why does my code work?

Comment: The element itself has an `onclick` property—they’re connected because the event handler is explicitly attached?

Comment: When you say "*to create or select an element, and then attach event handlers to the element*", how does that imply a `name` or `id` attribute on the element?

Comment: An DOM element doesn't need a `name` or `id` to work. If you're writing plain HTML, you also don't need an `name` or `id`, but you can still set an event listener on the element.

Comment: I guess like a javascript object, the engine gives each element a private identifier to know where to retreive it from memory. It is not linked to your question, but in JS when you pass an object as parameter for example, you don't pass actually the full object, but this hidden identifier (the reference to it)

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm asking. When writing plain HTML, it feels obvious that the event handler is explicitly attached to the element. However when manipulating the DOM programmatically, I was expecting that some form of explicit id would be a requirement

Comment: @jsm Why? It’s not a requirement when writing HTML.

Comment: Most tutorials start with assigning and selecting elements using some form of identifier, so I guess I have just 'internalised' that as a necessary prerequisite to doing anything with an element. I like @Kaddath's explanation: it makes sense that there must be a private identity for each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What identifier is being used to map the event to the correct div?

None. Event handlers are attached to the div element itself, an [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)) with an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)) that lives in the DOM tree. There exists no "mapping", and no selectors are used.

This does not require a `name` or an `id` attribute on the element (which would not necessarily even be unique, although it should be), elements can be selected through many means - all you need to attach the event handler is a reference to the element. And notice that you could even change the `name` or `id` of the element afterwards, the event listener would still be bound to the *same* element.